# Error 25 during equivs build Fake Packages for TexLive2015

Tags: texlive

According to [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373) **Fake packages**

```
$ sudo apt-get install equivs --no-install-recommends
$ mkdir -p /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs
$ equivs-control texlive-local
```

I change the content of `texlive-local` file to https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2015-ex.txt 
and I try to build

```
$ equivs-build texlive-local
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
sh: 1: cannot open package: No such file
sh: 1: defaults: not found
dh_prep: rm -f debian/<package name; defaults to equivs-dummy>.*.debhelper returned exit code 127
make: *** [install] Error 25
Error in the build process: exit status 2
```

Comment: No problem at all using Ubuntu 14.04. are you sure you made a proper download of the `.txt` file and copied it to `texlive-local` (BTW: since you owerwrite the `texlive-local` file, the `equivs-control` part is not needed, it just makes a template

Comment: before building you could to a `cat texlive-local` and see if the contents is the same as you get if you open the link in a browser

Comment: @daleif Done the steps again, and it's fine. Don't know what happened previous.

Comment: I usually blame cosmic radiation

Comment: Can you send the output of `dpkg -l equivs` and `dpkg -L equivs`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced (even by the OP - see comments) and the problem has vanished into the ether. Suggested diagnosis is cosmic radiation which is off-topic here but might be of interest on Physics SE.

Answer (score 1):

As a simplest way,

```
$ equivs-control texlive-local
$ cp debian-equivs-2015-ex.txt texlive-local
$ equivs-build texlive-local
```

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!